# Azure Pipelines compare Key Vault Secrets in Condition

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a simple value stored in a Key Vault that my Azure Pipelines has access to.

When I pull the value and compare it to a provided parameter, the comparison always fails even when I explicitly set it correctly. Is there something incorrect with the logic I have below that causes the comparison to fail or is it something I simply cannot do in Azure Pipelines?

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  displayName: "Download Key Vault Data"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure: MY_SERVICE_CONNECTION'
    KeyVaultName: 'myKeyVault23123'
    SecretsFilter: 'my-actual'
    RunAsPreJob: false

- bash: echo "EXECUTION REQUIRED ${DESIRED} vs ${ACTUAL})"
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.desired }}', '$(my-actual)'))
  displayName: "Detected: Necessary"
  env:
    ACTAUL: $(my-actual)
    DESIRED: ${{ parameters.desired }}

- bash: echo "execution NOT required ${DESIRED} vs ${ACTUAL})"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.desired }}', '$(my-actual)'))
  displayName: "Detected: Unnecessary"
  env:
    ACTAUL: $(my-actual)
    DESIRED: ${{ parameters.desired }}
```

If I explicitly set `my-actual` in the Key Vault, I my check still fails. I tried putting it in the script and running it a couple times in a row as well:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Setting Value Explicitly
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: "Azure: MY_SERVICE_CONNECTION"
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: az keyvault secret set --vault-name myKeyVault23123 --name my-actual --value "${{ parameters.desired }}"
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    useGlobalConfig: true
```

Comment: Added some shell scripts to confirm the value is set properly. Worst case scenario is I can use those to do the conditional values as a workaround.

Comment: What error you are getting as an output? Can you share the exact error messagE?

Comment: @Bruno no error at all I just see: `EXECUTION REQUIRED *** vs ***`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is a secret than it is always marked as `***` to protect your secret. So this is totally normal that you see `EXECUTION REQUIRED *** vs ***`.

I made also a test for these values:

- parameters.desired = test, my-actual = test I got `EXECUTION REQUIRED *** vs )`
- parameters.desired = test123test, my-actual = test I got `EXECUTION REQUIRED ***123*** vs )`

What is strange that for the first pipeline didn't go into `execution NOT required`, but values were the same. As this I would say that this is not possible to use secrets in conditions.

I got still the same messages, however with correct behavior I achieved with this pipeline:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: desired
  displayName: Desired
  type: string
  default: test

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- bash: |
    echo '$(my-actual)'
    echo '${{ parameters.desired }}'

- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent]false"
    if [ "${{ parameters.desired }}" == "$(my-actual)" ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent]true"
    fi

- bash: echo "EXECUTION REQUIRED ${DESIRED} vs ${ACTUAL})"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['skipsubsequent'], 'false'))
  displayName: "Detected: Necessary"
  env:
    ACTAUL: $(my-actual)
    DESIRED: ${{ parameters.desired }}

- bash: echo "execution NOT required ${DESIRED} vs ${ACTUAL})"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['skipsubsequent'], 'true'))
  displayName: "Detected: Unnecessary"
  env:
    ACTAUL: $(my-actual)
    DESIRED: ${{ parameters.desired }}
```

[image]

Comment: Setting the variables seems to work. I'd prefer to directly use the Key Vault data, but it seems like it's not going to work.